# Creating an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class called `ElementInfo`

```
public class ElementInfo {

    public String name;
    public String symbol;
    public double mass;

}
```

Then I attempt to create an array of `ElementInfo` like so:

```
ElementInfo e[] = new ElementInfo[2];

e[0].symbol = "H";
e[0].name = "Hydrogen";
e[0].mass = 1.008;

//...
```

Dont tell me i have to call `new` for every instance of the class!

Can I do this:

```
ElementInfo e[] = new ElementInfo[100];
for(ElementInfo element: e){
    e = new ElementInfo();
}
```

Comment: Then, how would you like to do that? Do you have any other thoughts in mind?

Comment: Be careful on what you call a class and an object. You've created an array of objects, which are of a specific class.

Comment: i meant to say an array of class objects

Comment: i updated my question. can i create a bunch of objects like i shown?

Comment: So, what week of Java 101 are you in? I'm gonna guess week 2. Maybe I'm way off base, but if I'm not, please add the 'homework' tag. And best of luck with your class :)

Comment: @nick "array of class objects", should be "array of object instances" or "array of instance references"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call new for every element of the class.

```
public class ElementInfo {

    private String name;
    private String symbol;
    private double mass;

    public String get_name() { return name; }
    public String get_symbol() { return symbol; }
    public double get_mass() { return mass; }

    public ElementInfo(name, symbol, mass) {
        this.name = name;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.mass = mass;
    }
}
```

Then create them like so:

```
e[0] = new ElementInfo("H", "Hydrogen", 1.008);
```

Comment: a constructor forces me to input name, symbol, and mass for every element. i want the class to act like a structure

Comment: that also means that you leave the object in an inconsistent state as you assign to it.  For future best practice and as your systems grow complex objects like this should be immutable after construction which eliminates any concern about inconsistency or contention.

Answer (score 3):

> Dont tell me i have to call NEW for every instance of the class!

Exactly.

You just created an array of nulls.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new instance for each element, but it's not hard :

```
ElementInfo e[] = new ElementInfo[2];
for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
    e[i] = new ElementInfo();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ElementInfo e[] = new ElementInfo[2];

e[0] = new ElementInfo();
e[0].symbol = 'H'; ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to do.

When you create the array you just create the space for the references to the actual objects. Initially the value is `null`.

To put references to an object, you do an assignation

```
e[0] = new ElementInfo();
```

or

```
ElementInfo a = new ElementInfo();
....
e[0] = a;
```

Relax, typing will be the last of your problems as a programmer :-D

Comment: well good thing i can copy/paste and use regular expressions :)

Answer (score 1):

By declaring an array, instances of that array's type *do not* automatically fill the array.

```
e[0] = new ElementInfo();
```

You can also instantiate an object at every index easily with a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i] = new ElementInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Right now its an array that holds ElementInfo objects but each index is null.

Why don't you create a constructor that takes the arguments. Then

```
ElementInfo [] elements = {new ElementInfo("H", "Hydrogen", 1.008), new ElementInfo("C", ....)};
```

Comment: Because perhaps some elements will have more parameters and i rather keep it in this format

Answer (score 0):

```
ElementInfo e[] = new ElementInfo[100]; 
for(ElementInfo element: e){ 
    e = new ElementInfo(); 
}
```

You cannot do that because `e` is an array type variable, which means you cannot assign to it a reference to an of object of type `ElementInfo`. `e = new ElementInfo();` is what I am referring to.

Look at the [answer by Dalmus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12325743/738746).